# Recover Parent from Pointer-to-member

Tags: c++, parent, pointer-to-member

Suppose that we have a pointer-to-class member pointing at a field of a class.  We also have a pointer to that specific field in a particular instance of the class.  For example, we might have something like this:

```
class A {
     B inner_object;
}

A* myA = /* ... */
B* ptr = &myA->inner_object;
B A::* memPtr = &A::inner_object;
```

Is there a way to use `ptr` and `memPtr` to recover `myA`?  That is, if we didn't already have an explicit pointer for `myA`, could we make one out of `ptr` and `memPtr`?

Comment: Could you be more clear. I don't understand what you want to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a decent amount of research...

This is actually done in most industrial intrusive list implementations. It does require some hackery, however.

Boost intrusive structures use the following (and yes, it is implementation specific)

```
template<class Parent, class Member>
inline const Parent *parent_from_member(const Member *member, const Member Parent::*   ptr_to_member)
{
   return (const Parent*)((const char*)member -
      offset_from_pointer_to_member(ptr_to_member));
}


template<class Parent, class Member>
inline std::ptrdiff_t offset_from_pointer_to_member(const Member Parent::* ptr_to_member)
{
   //The implementation of a pointer to member is compiler dependent.
   #if defined(BOOST_INTRUSIVE_MSVC_COMPLIANT_PTR_TO_MEMBER)
   //msvc compliant compilers use their the first 32 bits as offset (even in 64 bit mode)
   return *(const boost::int32_t*)(void*)&ptr_to_member;
   //This works with gcc, msvc, ac++, ibmcpp
   #elif defined(__GNUC__)   || defined(__HP_aCC) || defined(BOOST_INTEL) || \
     defined(__IBMCPP__) || defined(__DECCXX)
   const Parent * const parent = 0;
   const char *const member = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&(parent->*ptr_to_member));
   return std::ptrdiff_t(member - reinterpret_cast<const char*>(parent));
   #else
   //This is the traditional C-front approach: __MWERKS__, __DMC__, __SUNPRO_CC
   return (*(const std::ptrdiff_t*)(void*)&ptr_to_member) - 1;
   #endif
}
```

Essentially the same thing (albeit in C) as is done in the linux kernel to manage intrusive lists, with the container_of macro (but of course ptr-to-members are not used):

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({ \
            const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr); 
            (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't. A pointer-to-member has no knowledge of any instance of the class that it is a member of. That's why you need an instance anytime you want to *access* the member through the pointer.

A pointer-to-member is *not* a pointer. Indeed, it was probably a mistake on the C++ committee's part to even call it a pointer. On many (if not most) implementations, even the sizes of a pointer are not equal to the size of a pointer-to-member. There's no offset tricks you can play here. And even if you found a way, if you parsed the data in a pointer-to-member, it still would be specific to that implementation.

Comment: I think the implied question is: can we e.g. subtract one from the other to obtain a pointer-to-object?

Comment: Ok, but if we think of the ptr-to-member simply as an offset, the parent should be trivially recoverable. You're saying a ptr-to-member isn't an offset, or can't be made to behave like one? (EDIT: what oli said)

Comment: @Oli - why give people crazy ideas?:-)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: That can't be done either, because a pointer-to-member is not a pointer. Casting it will not work either, because sizeof(pointer-to-member) != sizeof(pointer).

Comment: @Nicol: Sure.  But I think your answer should mention this, because I think that's the kind of idea that the OP was implying.  (notwithstanding the fact that *wanting* to do this probably implies a design error.)

Comment: @bcr: A pointer-to-member is a pointer-to-member. Just like an int is an int and a float is a float. It is a distinct type of data.

Comment: Lol sorry, I mean how is it encoded? It must be a number, basically, no?

Comment: @bcr: It is encoded in a way defined by each implementation. There is no standard way for implementing pointer-to-members. Think of it as a black box.

Comment: @bcr It is implementation dependent. If I remember correctly, the size of a pointer to non-virtual member function on MSVC is 8 bytes, for a virtual function it is 12 bytes, while regular pointers (including pointers to static members functions, I think) are 4 bytes. So they contain more information than a simple memory address.

Comment: mm, alright. Thanks a lot for the help. For the record/for completeness, here was my thinking on why this would be nice: I'm writing an intrusive list class, and it would be nice for the member_hook class members `next` and `prev` to only point to other member_hooks. But then, if I did something like `node->*hook->next`, I can't actually recover the original node referred to by next. If ptr-to-members could be used as I was thinking, this could be done.

Comment: @Oli, if this is a design error, then the primary list implementation for linux, as well as boost intrusive lists, are badly designed. This is a reasonable thing to want to do, the fact that ptr-to-member is designed like it is just makes this more difficult than need be.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

A pointer to member does not store information about any particular instance.

It knows only a type, and a pointer to a function within that type.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not standard and not really recommended for actual use, but you can try this:

```
A *fake_A= reinterpret_cast<A *>(1);
B *fake_B= &(fake_A->*ptr_to_member);
char *fake_A_raw= static_cast<char *>(static_cast<void *>(fake_A));
char *fake_B_raw= static_cast<char *>(static_cast<void *>(fake_B));

ptrdiff_t offset_to_A_from_B= fake_B - fake_A;

char *member_raw= static_cast<char *>(static_cast<void *>(member));
char *base_raw= member_raw - offset_to_A_from_B;
A *base= static_cast<A *>(static_cast<void *>(base_raw));
```

And you really shouldn't do this.

Comment: and why are you posting this ? :P

Comment: Haha yes, that's a pretty awesome example. But there are probably easier ways to do essentially the same thing with what we have available, don't you think? E.g., if you have a pointer to some struct of type A, you can just get the offset from subtracting a pointer to the desired field from the pointer to the struct. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @bcr, true, but that's not what you asked for. You wanted to know given a pointer to member how to get back to the root class; you cannot cast a pointer to member to an offset directly. For example, null pointer to member does not have to be bitwise zero.

Comment: @YeenFei, it's just a riff on some older code Scott Bilas published in one of the Game programming gems. The pointer cast of 1 instead of 0 is what makes it all work.

Comment: @MSN. Good point, I didn't read the code quite closely enough. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible and is very useful. Pointer to member is just an offset as long as you are sure of what type of structure contains the pointer to member.